# Select columns on match with vector and create ifelse condition with their content

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have a dataset with over several diseases, 0 indicating not having the disease and 1 having the disease.

To illustrate it with an example: I am interested in Diseases A and whether the people in the dataset have this diseases on its own or as the cause of another disease. Therefore I want to create a new variable "Type" with the values "NotDiseasedWithA", "Primary" and "Secondary". The diseases that can cause A are contained in a vector "SecondaryCauses":

```
SecondaryCauses = c("DiseaseB", "DiseaseD")
```

"NotDiseasedWithA" means that they do not have disease A.
"Primary" means that they have disease A but not any of the known diseases that can cause it.
"Secondary" means that they have disease A and a diseases that probably caused it.

Sample data

```
ID  DiseaseA    DiseaseB    DiseaseC    DiseaseD    DiseaseE
1   0           1           0           0           0
2   1           0           0           0           1
3   1           0           1           1           0
4   1           0           1           1           1
5   0           0           0           0           0
```

My question is:

1. How do I select the columns I am interested in? I have more than 20 columns that are not ordered. Therefore I created the vector.
2. How do I create the condition based on the content of the diseases I am interested in?

I tried something like the following, but this did not work:

```
DF %>% mutate(Type = ifelse(DiseaseA == 0, "NotDiseasedWithA", ifelse(sum(names(DF) %in% SecondaryCauses) > 0, "Secondary", "Primary")))
```

So in the end I want to have this results:

```
ID  DiseaseA    DiseaseB    DiseaseC    DiseaseD    DiseaseE    Type
1   0           1           0           0           0           NotDiseasedWithA
2   1           0           0           0           1           Primary
3   1           0           1           1           0           Secondary
4   1           0           1           1           1           Secondary
5   0           0           0           0           0           NotDiseasedWithA
```

Comment: Why you want Primary in the first row while it has a zero for DiseaseA and why you want NotDiseasedWithA on the second row while it has a 1 for DiseaseA. Please make sure your expected outcome is correct on the textual explanation you gave.

Comment: I interchanged them. Now they're correct. Thx for the note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**using data.table**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, DiseaseA = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), DiseaseB = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), DiseaseC = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), DiseaseD = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), DiseaseE = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("data.frame"))

library(data.table)

setDT(df) # make it a data.table

SecondaryCauses = c("DiseaseB", "DiseaseD")

df[DiseaseA == 0, Type := "NotDiseasedWithA"][DiseaseA == 1, Type := ifelse(rowSums(.SD) > 0, "Secondary", "Primary"), .SDcols = SecondaryCauses]

df

#    ID DiseaseA DiseaseB DiseaseC DiseaseD DiseaseE             Type
# 1:  1        0        1        0        0        0 NotDiseasedWithA
# 2:  2        1        0        0        0        1          Primary
# 3:  3        1        0        1        1        0        Secondary
# 4:  4        1        0        1        1        1        Secondary
# 5:  5        0        0        0        0        0 NotDiseasedWithA
```